# How to mark all files in the current dired directory?

Tags: dired

I want to mark all the files in the current dired buffer. Is there a command for this? Not including `.` and `..`.

My use case is hardlinking all the files in a directory and I always reach for `M` which is change mode. I can remove all marks with either (?) `U` `unmark-all-marks` or `M-DEL` `unmark-all-files`, and it would seem normal to have the opposite.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<kbd>U</kbd> (if necessary) followed by <kbd>t</kbd>

- `dired-unmark-all-marks`
- `dired-toggle-marks`

Comment: There is also the more explicit option `* s` (`dired-mark-subdir-files`), now with 100% more key presses!

Comment: An excellent point -- particularly when multiple sub-directories have been inserted into the buffer.

Answer (score 10):

@phils provided the answer (which should be accepted, IMO).

If you use library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can also do what you ask in some other ways.

In particular, commands, such as **`H`** (`dired-do-hardlink`), that normally act on the *marked* files and directories (or on the *N* next such) let you use a special *prefix argument* to act on ***all*** of the displayed files and dirs, regardless of which ones are marked.

This can be convenient when you have a set of markings that you don't want to change just to be able to issue a one-off command that acts on all files.

These are the special prefix arguments that provide this Dired+ feature:

- **`C-u C-u`**: all *files* listed - *no* directories (including `.` and `..`)
- **`C-u C-u C-u`**: all files and directories listed *except* **`.`** and **`..`**
- **`C-u C-u C-u C-u`**: all files and directories listed (including `.` and `..`)

(As usual, a *numeric* prefix arg *N* acts on the next *N* files and dirs (or the previous *N* if *N* is negative, and any other prefix arg means act on just the file or dir of the current line.)

So in your case, if you want to hard-link all of the files and directories except for `.` and `..` then you could use `C-u C-u C-u H`. And if you didn't want to hard-link any directories then you could use `C-u C-u H`.